# why does useCallback return an empty array

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

in react native app,

i'm trying to get data from async function which will bring me back Promise<AlarmType[] | undefined>

Q1. so, in getAlarms.then() function, the undefined case is filtered and an **empty array is printed in my console.**

and after saving code in vscode, the console prints an array with proper data

Q2.the reason why i use useLayoutEffect and useEffect separately is
i just wanna separate the data fetching code from the react navigation header setOption code
but i'm not sure if it is a good practice

Is there any better ways to do this?
edit: i’m using react-native-simple-alarm

```
  const [alarms, setAlarms] = useState<AlarmType[]>([]);

  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    getAlarms().then(response => {
      if (response) setAlarms(response);
      else console.log('undefined | empty array returned');
    });
  }, []);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    const willFocusSubscription = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      fetchData();
    });
      console.log(alarms) // here, this function is called twice, and return empty array
    return willFocusSubscription;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => <Icon name="trash-can-outline" size={30} 
          onPress={() => {
            deleteAllAlarms();
            fetchData();
          }}/>,
      headerTitle: 'Alarm',
      headerRight: () =><Icon name="plus" size={30} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ModalStackView')}/>,
    });
  }, []);
```

in getAlarms.ts

```
export const getAlarms = async () => {
  try {
    return await RNGetAlarms();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('setting call error' + error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Which npm you are using for RNGetAlarms ?

Comment: @VickyAhuja it’s simple-alarm

Comment: I want to know from where you are importing or using it?

Comment: @VickyAhuja in getAlarms.ts import getAlarms as RNGetAlarm from simple-alarm

Comment: have you called createAlarm first to create alarm?

Comment: sure i did, i can see the alarm instance after refreshing the ios simulator

Comment: Okay, so your question 1 resolved right?

Comment: i mean it has to be rerendered by itself without me refreshing the simulator

Comment: I am dropping an answer please have a try with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **useLayoutEffect is called before the render cycle of React which means before rendering the JSX content in your code this hook is being called**.

So, If there is any requirement before JSX render like change header name, show header left or right buttons, etc.

and **the useEffect is called after the initial render cycle is completed**. when the JSX code is done with the rendering UI part.

So, I think your code should look like below:

```
const [alarms, setAlarms] = useState<AlarmType[]>([]);

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    getAlarms().then(response => {
        if (response) setAlarms(response);
        else console.log('undefined | empty array returned');
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const willFocusSubscription = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        fetchData();
    });
    return willFocusSubscription;
}, [fetchData, navigation]);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerLeft: () => <Icon name="trash-can-outline" size={30} 
            onPress={() => {
                deleteAllAlarms();
                fetchData();
            }}/>,
        headerTitle: 'Alarm',
        headerRight: () =><Icon name="plus" size={30} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ModalStackView')}/>,
    });
}, [deleteAllAlarms, fetchData, navigation]);
```

Comment: thank your for your assistance, but it still gives me an empty array at the first

Comment: @soohyukhong, What is you app flow can you please put here ?

Comment: sorry to take so  long, I figured out what was wrong with it.

Comment: @soohyukhong, Does your issue resolved?

Comment: As long as my alarm data is not stored in the process(i get it from the async functions of the alarm package), so I should have return Promise<Alarm[] | []> from all of the async function, NOT only getAlarms but also deleteAlarms, editAlarms, etc.

Comment: and i changed fetchData func to be called after a Promise is returned. Like, deleteAllAlarms().then(res => {setAlarms([])})

Comment: @soohyukhong, Great to hear that you got a workaround for your issue.

Comment: yeah, thanks. You helped me a lot